# Generalizing Clojure solution to Euler # 1

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Q = Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

Simplest answer

```
(reduce + (filter #(or (== (mod % 3) 0) (== (mod % 5) 0)) (range 1000)))
```

Trying for generic answer like following

```
(reduce + (list-nums-divisible-by-all-divisors N div1 div2 ...))
(defn list-nums-divisible-by-all-divisors
    [num & divisors]
    (let [myfn (create-fn divisors)]
        (filter myfn (range num))))
```

Here is create-fn for 2 divisors

```
(defn create-fn
  [div1 div2]
  #(or (== (mod % div1) 0) (== (mod % div2) 0)))
```

How would I write create-fn for variable number of divisors?

Is this the right approach to tackle this? I have a feeling that I should probably be using the -> or ->> operator, instead of this way.

Also, I think this becomes a generic question. Can one create and return a function using a variable number of arguments, which can then be used as an anonymous function (with another level of arguments)?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I know you could do it with a macro, but I suspect there's a way to do it with ordinary functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend going a little more granular, building several predicates and then combining them using [`every-pred`](http://conj.io/store/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0-alpha4/clojure.core/every-pred/). This function builds one predicate out of several, pretty conveniently.

First, start with a curried divisibility function:

```
(defn divisible-by? [n]
  (fn [x]
    (zero? (rem x n))))
```

Currying just means that in order to have a function "taking two arguments", we first accept one argument and then build a function which takes the second argument. These are used like

```
((divisible-by? 3) 6) ;;-> true
```

In this case we want that behaviour because we want to `map` a function which creates unary predicates, like so:

```
(defn create-fn [divisors]
  (apply every-pred (map divisible-by? divisors)))
```

Comment: Thanks!  I needed to change "every-pred" to "some-fn" since we need to check for divisibility by 3 OR 5. I knew about currying functions, but the ability every-pred or some-pred over such functions seems great.